# == operator defined for std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary

the `std::map` refernce at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/
does not mention any `==` oprerator. But my code containing `m1==m2` compiles (where m1 and m2 are of types `map<,>` ) . What does `==` for maps do?
Am I looking at an out-dated reference?

Comment: FYI: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operators/ -- It's not listed on the page you linked because that page is for member functions, and the operator is implemented as a free function.  It's listed in the sidebar of the page you linked to though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are looking at an outdated reference. It does what you would expect: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_cmp

Comment: @AbhishekAnand yep. You can also look at the source code if you want (which you have since it's a template).

Comment: thanks Seth .. I had deleted my comment because your updated answer answered it